# How can I pass a handler function that may not be defined yet or may change at some point?

Tags: javascript

I ask this question because I feel like there is a cleaner way to solve this problem than using an anonymous function to wrap the call.

```
    // This does not work because it passes the value found 
    // at obj.init at the time of binding.  

    scope.on('anEvent', obj.init);

    // This works because it is wrapped in the anonymous function and the  
    // obj.init method that gets run is whatever it is currently defined as.

    scope.on('anEvent', function() { obj.init(); });
```

I want the most up to date method (obj.init) to be called whenever 'anEvent' is emitted.

Comment: maybe try `scope.$on('anEvent', obj.init.bind(obj))`

Comment: I know that the second approach works, I just feel like there could be a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to do it cleaner honestly, since you cannot modify the scope.$on function, and also I am not sure what that function does, since you have not specified the framework and it is most certinly not pure javascript.

With modification of the $on function it would be possible, but would require a lot of modifications of the entire system probably, since it was not though of when it was being made.

Comment: @DerekMT12 binding the init method will just return the method at the time of (event) binding and the problem will persist

Answer (score 1):

You're not binding *variables*, you're binding *values*. A raw `obj.init` will bind *the value* at this moment as event handler. You can't bind "the variable" and have its value re-evaluated later. To re-evaluate the variable at the time of the event firing, this is indeed the most straight forward option:

```
scope.on('anEvent', function() { obj.init(); });
```

Comment: I am aware that passing just obj.init will just pass the value of obj.init as the handler. I just feel like there probably exists something like obj.callMethod('init') that is essentially the same as wrapping it in an anonymous function.

Comment: Nope, there isn't, unless you create such a thing. And even then, the anonymous function wrapper is much more straight forward and/or does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problems with first implementation would be:

1. Try to access to property before assigning functionality to it.
2. function was added but is related to parent object.

#### Access before assignment

```
var obj = {};
scope.on(event, obj.callback)
obj.callback = function(){ console.log('this function wont be called on event'); };
```

#### Relation to `obj` variable

```
var obj = {
  callback: function() { console.log(this.str); },
  str: 'This string wont be sent out'
}
this.str = 'Maybe this is the one to come out';

scope.on(event, obj.callback);
```